# Add Remove Multi Select Field

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I have multiple Add/Remove Multiple Select Fields on a form.  I have 2 questions regarding how I can accomplish two different functions.

1. How do I get multiple values (that I am pulling into the field using MySQL) that are placed in the 'Add', to be parsed and placed into a field or email separated by a comma.
2. I have 6 groups of these multiple select fields.  When the user selects the value and moves it to be added, I want the values to removed from the other groups, so that they can not be added.

Here is the my code:

JS:

```
 //GROUP 1
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$().ready(function() {  
$('#add').click(function() {  
return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');  
});  
$('#remove').click(function() {  
return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');  
});  
});
</script>

//GROUP 2
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$().ready(function() {  
$('#add2').click(function() {  
return !$('#select3 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select4');  
});  
$('#remove2').click(function() {  
return !$('#select4 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select3');  
});  
}); 
</script>

//GROUP 3
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$().ready(function() {  
$('#add3').click(function() {  
return !$('#select5 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select6');  
});  
$('#remove3').click(function() {  
return !$('#select6 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select5');  
});  
}); 
</script>

//GROUP 4
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$().ready(function() {  
$('#add4').click(function() {  
return !$('#select7 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select8');  
});  
$('#remove3').click(function() {  
return !$('#select8 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select7');  
});  
}); 
</script>

//GROUP 5
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$().ready(function() {  
$('#add5').click(function() {  
return !$('#select9 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select10');  
});  
$('#remove5').click(function() {  
return !$('#select9 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select10');  
});  
}); 
</script>

//GROUP 6
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$().ready(function() {  
$('#add6').click(function() {  
return !$('#select11 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select12');  
});  
$('#remove6').click(function() {  
return !$('#select12 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select11');  
});  
}); 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
//GROUP 1
<select name="select1" [] multiple class="calloutForm" id="select1" title="<?      php echo $row_allUsers['submittername']; ?>">
          <?php
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_allUsersDynamicList['submittername']? >"><?php  echo $row_allUsersDynamicList['submittername']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_allUsersDynamicList = mysql_fetch_assoc($allUsersDynamicList));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($allUsersDynamicList);
if($rows > 0) {
mysql_data_seek($allUsersDynamicList, 0);
$row_allUsersDynamicList = mysql_fetch_assoc($allUsersDynamicList);
 }
?>
</select>
</div></td>
<td width="138" rowspan="2"><div align="center">&gt;&gt;&gt;</div></td>
<td width="181"><div align="left">
<select name="select2" multiple class="calloutForm" id="select2">
</select>

//GROUP 2
<td width="139"><div align="right">
<select name="select3" multiple="multiple" class="calloutForm" id="select3"    title="<?php echo $row_allUsers['submittername']; ?>">
<?php
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_allUsersDynamicList['submittername']?>"><?php   echo $row_allUsersDynamicList['submittername']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_allUsersDynamicList = mysql_fetch_assoc($allUsersDynamicList));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($allUsersDynamicList);
if($rows > 0) {
mysql_data_seek($allUsersDynamicList, 0);
$row_allUsersDynamicList = mysql_fetch_assoc($allUsersDynamicList);
}
?>
</select>
</div></td>

//GROUP 3
<td width="139"><div align="right">
<select name="select5" multiple="multiple" class="calloutForm"     id="select5" title="<?php echo $row_allUsers['submittername']; ?>">
<?php
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_allUsersDynamicList['submittername']?>"><?php    echo $row_allUsersDynamicList['submittername']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_allUsersDynamicList = mysql_fetch_assoc($allUsersDynamicList));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($allUsersDynamicList);
if($rows > 0) {
mysql_data_seek($allUsersDynamicList, 0);
$row_allUsersDynamicList = mysql_fetch_assoc($allUsersDynamicList);
}
?>
</select>
/div></td>

//GROUP 4
<td width="139"><div align="right">
<select name="select7" multiple="multiple" class="calloutForm"   id="select7" title="<?php echo $row_allUsers['submittername']; ?>">
<?php
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_allUsersDynamicList['submittername']?>"><?php echo $row_allUsersDynamicList['submittername']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_allUsersDynamicList = mysql_fetch_assoc($allUsersDynamicList));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($allUsersDynamicList);
if($rows > 0) {
mysql_data_seek($allUsersDynamicList, 0);
$row_allUsersDynamicList = mysql_fetch_assoc($allUsersDynamicList);
}
?>
</select>
</div></td>

//GROUP 5
<td width="139"><div align="right">
        <select name="select9" multiple="multiple" class="calloutForm"    id="select9" title="<?php echo $row_allUsers['submittername']; ?>">
<?php
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_allUsersDynamicList['submittername']?>"><?php echo $row_allUsersDynamicList['submittername']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_allUsersDynamicList = mysql_fetch_assoc($allUsersDynamicList));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($allUsersDynamicList);
if($rows > 0) {
mysql_data_seek($allUsersDynamicList, 0);
$row_allUsersDynamicList = mysql_fetch_assoc($allUsersDynamicList);
}
?>
</select>
</div></td>

//GROUP 6
<td width="139"><div align="right">
        <select name="select11" multiple="multiple" class="calloutForm"   id="select11" title="<?php echo $row_allUsers['submittername']; ?>">
<?php
do {  
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_allUsersDynamicList['submittername']?>"><?php echo $row_allUsersDynamicList['submittername']?></option>
<?php
} while ($row_allUsersDynamicList = mysql_fetch_assoc($allUsersDynamicList));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($allUsersDynamicList);
if($rows > 0) {
mysql_data_seek($allUsersDynamicList, 0);
$row_allUsersDynamicList = mysql_fetch_assoc($allUsersDynamicList);
}
?>
</select>
</div></td>
```

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Please can you simplify your code down to JUST what is relevant to your question. More people will look at it that way, few will plow through all that code.

Comment: The JS part, is it included in 1 page?